# R purrr:map on a grouped/nested tibble

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to apply a function across columns of a nested grouped tibble as in the example below.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- swiss %>%
  group_by(Catholic > 20) %>%
  nest()
```

Which results in a tibble that looks like:

```
> df
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   Catholic > 20 [2]
  `Catholic > 20` data             
  <lgl>           <list>           
1 FALSE           <tibble [26 × 6]>
2 TRUE            <tibble [21 × 6]>
```

Now I make some function to build a model

```
fit <- function(df, modL = NA){
  if (modL == 1) {fit <- lm(Fertility ~ Education, data = df)}
  if (modL == 2) {fit <- lm(Fertility ~ Education + Examination, data = df)}
  fit
}
```

Now I map that model to columns of the grouped data and make two new variables to store the model fits.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(model1 = map(data, fit, modL = 1)) %>%
  mutate(model2 = map(data, fit, modL = 2))
```

Which produces a tibble with two new columns that contain the model fits

```
> df
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Catholic > 20 [2]
  `Catholic > 20` data              model1 model2
  <lgl>           <list>            <list> <list>
1 FALSE           <tibble [26 × 6]> <lm>   <lm>  
2 TRUE            <tibble [21 × 6]> <lm>   <lm>
```

What I want to achieve is a purr-type map function that does the same thing as the following code.

```
anova(df$model1[[1]], df$model2[[1]])
anova(df$model1[[2]], df$model2[[2]])
```

I though the following code would work, but it does not.

```
map(df[,3:4], anova)
```

Gurus, how do I map a function across columns of a nested and grouped dataset to give one result per row using the columns of that row as input?

Brant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  mutate(anova = map2(model1, model2, ~ anova(.x,.y)))%>%
  mutate(pvalue = map_dbl(anova, ~.$`Pr(>F)`[2]))
```

I think this is what you want? Can you clarify please! Second mutate will pull out the p-value of the anova for each pairwise comparison.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. I was thinking something like this initially `map(df[,3:4], print)`  because I did not need to store the result of `anova`. When I tried `df %>% map2(model1, model2, ~anova(.x, .y))` it did not work.

Comment: Also @zimia, what if there were more than two models to compare with `anova`, would it still work?

Comment: in that case use `mutate(anova = pmap(list(model1, model2, model3), ~ anova(..1,..2,..3)))` for three models. just add more to the list if you want to compare more and iterate into ..4, ..5 and so on.